# Is there any shortcuts for writing multiple hover CSS properties in one line?

Tags: html, css

Suppose if I want to write hover CSS property for multiple classes,
I have to write like this.

```
a:hover, p:hover, div:hover{
// CSS properties 
}
```

Each time I have to give colon to class and write hover, its repeatedly we should write hover for all classes.
So My question is can we minimize this code by just writing hover only once for multiple classes? Is there any shortcut for that?

Comment: just create a new class and add it to all the elements you want the hover style. `.hoverClass:hover { }`, then `<a class="hoverClass">` etc. Also, those are tags not classes in your example.

Comment: if you use a pre-processor like SCSS, you can do something like `div, a, p { &:hover { /* insert properties here */ } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the same class for all your hover effects, then it would be `.myClass:hover {}` OR you could use multiple classes which start with the same text.

Here is an example:

```css
div[class^="icon-"]:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-home">Div 1</div>
<div class="icon-search">Div 2</div>
<div class="icon-edit">Div 3</div>
```

Well, it is not necessary that it STARTS with that text. You could use the following comparison operators as well:

`=` = equals

`^=` = starts with

`$=` = ends with

`*=` = contains

`~=` = contains in a list

Comment: This is great one, I was not knowing whether we can use write like this also.. Thank you for ur support

Comment: @AnandS you're welcome! If it helped you, please mark this answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It has only shipped in Safari to day, but is being implemented in both Firefox and Chrome.

`:matches(a, p, div):hover` will cover your use case. PostCSS currently has a plugin included in postcss-preset-env if you would like to use it today.

Answer (score -1):

as per the css working principle we can not do that. :hover, :visited these are all css pseudo classes. As per your ask, as the elements are different(a, p, div) to identify them separately we need to separate them using comma. And if you write

```
a, p, div:hover{
```

then it will activate the css of a and p at normal condiftion instead of when hovered(that will only happen to div).

Hence we need to write

```
a:hover, p:hover, div:hover
```

as we are mentioning different hover states for each element.